# ubuntu 16.04 bluetooth sending file Error: Unsupported Media Type

Tags: bluetooth, files, transfer

I transfered the file `filename.gpx` from Ubuntu 16.04 to mobile and get an error. In syslog I find:

```
Mar 10 10:24:55 lipa obexd[2802]: Transfer(0x5584ded061b0) Error: Unsupported Media Type
```

After that, I renamed file to `filename.txt` and transfer was successful. Why there is restriction to send files with `.gpx` (and maybe others) extension.

Comment: This is not Ubuntu problem. It's Bluetooth client (mobile) problem.